# Android Stripe Payment: user email?

Tags: android, email, stripe-payments, checkout

When implementing [Stripe](https://stripe.com) in our clients we found that the web widget [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/tutorial) asks for the user email, as you can see in the first image. This email information is needed because Stripe sends emails about the payment to the customers. But when implementing the widget of [Stripe Android Integration](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android) it doesn't ask for the email, as you can see in the second image. How and where can we send the email to Stripe in the Android app?

[image: Web widget]

[image: Android widged]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd actually need to collect the email separately.  When creating the charge, you'd pass it in as a `receipt_email` argument [[1](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge)][[2](https://stripe.com/docs/charges)].  If you're using a `CustomerSession` [[3](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android/customer-information)], the email should also be associated with the Customer [[4](https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_object)] that is associated with the session.

> [1] https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge 
>   [2] https://stripe.com/docs/charges 
>   [3] https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android/customer-information 
>   [4] https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_object